# Why do I need to enter WSL twice to make it work normally?

Tags: windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

First, I entered WSL but it looks abnormally - no color and alias:

[image: Abnormally bash]

And if I enter bash again everything goes to work normally:

[image: Normally bash]

After installation there was no shortcut for WSL so I created one:

[image: My shortcut]

But the problem seems to show up in recent insider builds. My windows version is 16184.1001.

So what's wrong with my WSL?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. See https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/2067.

> [@0xbadfca11](https://github.com/0xbadfca11) Before than 16184, bash's argv[0] is '/bin/bash'. This is non-login shell. Bash will only loads .bashrc.
>   Starting 16184, bash's argv[0] is '-bash'. This is login shell. Bash loads only the first one in .bash_profile or .bash_login or .profile. Don't see .bashrc. However, the default .profile will executes .bashrc.
>   Let's load .bashrc yourself when using .bash_profile or .bash_login which has higher priority than .profile.
>   Even if '-l' is added, .bashrc is not loaded because there are files with higher priority than .profile.